# Argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"

Tags: c++

This has probably been asked before but I can't seem to find the solution:

```
std::string GetPath()
{
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    ::GetSystemDirectory(buffer,MAX_PATH);
    strcat(buffer,"\\version.dll");

    return std::string(buffer);
}
```

This returns an error stating:

```
argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"
```

So yeah. Anyone got an answer?

Comment: GetSystemDirectory takes in a `TCHAR` array, which differs in size and type based on project settings and flags.

Comment: also, telling us which line the compiler is complaining about would be kind of helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use the ansi version:

```
std::string GetPath()
{
     char buffer[MAX_PATH] = {};
     ::GetSystemDirectoryA(buffer,_countof(buffer)); // notice the A
     strcat(buffer,"\\version.dll");

     return std::string(buffer);
 }
```

Or use unicode:

```
std::wstring GetPath()
{
     wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH] = {};
     ::GetSystemDirectoryW(buffer,_countof(buffer)); // notice the W, or drop the W to get it "by default"
     wcscat(buffer,L"\\version.dll");

     return std::wstring(buffer);
 }
```

Rather than call the A/W versions explicitly you can drop the A/W and configure the whole project to use ansi/unicode instead. All this will do is change some #defines to replace foo with fooA/W.

Notice that you should use _countof() to avoid incorrect sizes depending on the buffers type too.

Comment: @paulm This fixed it. Just waiting for the timer so I can mark it as solved :/

Comment: @OliverMller Do make sure that you choose the second option, and use Unicode.

Comment: @paulm No! Keep the faith! `TCHAR` is the last resort to be used only if you need to support Windows 98.

Comment: I've never really seen the use of TCHAR / _tcscat in any recent code - I guess this explains why :)

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your code using MultiByte support it will compile correctly,but when you compile it using Unicode flag it will give an error because in Unicode support ::GetSystemDirectoryA becomes ::GetSystemDirectoryW use consider using TCHAR instead of char.TCHAR is defined such that it becomes char in Multibyte flag and wchar_t with Unicode flag

```
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
::GetSystemDirectory(buffer,MAX_PATH);
_tcscat(buffer,_T("\\version.dll"));
```

You can use typedef for string /wstring so your code becomes independent

```
#ifdef UNICODE 
typedef wstring STRING;
#else
typedef string STRING;
#endif

STRING GetPath()
{
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
    ::GetSystemDirectory(buffer,MAX_PATH);
    _tcscat(buffer,_T("\\version.dll"));

    return STRING(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Will _tcscat map to strcat/wcscat?

Comment: This is accurate, but it's hard to justify the gross obfuscation of `TCHAR` these days. Only really useful if you want your code to run on Windows 98.

Comment: yes if you want use can build using Unicode flag and with a WCHAR instead of TCHAR

Comment: @kunal or just use the standard `wchar_t` and not the wacko macros.

Comment: @rubenvb thats more generic if you want to compile for both multibyte and unicode builds

Comment: There is no reason to compile Win32 non-UNICODE. Might as well use the right type and not use all these silly MS-isms.

Comment: so that is the reason for downvote...that was not the question that he had to compile for unicode..thank for making me realize i didn't know about all this stuff