# Can't convert Char to LPWSTR

Tags: c++, char, lpwstr

The following code

```
string exePath() {
string path;
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
cout << "reading path\n";
GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
string::size_type pos = string(buffer).find_last_of("\\/");
path = string(buffer).substr(0, pos)/*+"\\system.exe"*/;
return path;
```

}

gives me error at the second parameter in VisualStudio (buffer):

> the type "char *" argument is incompatible with the type parameter
>   "LPWSTR"

(translated from italian,i have vs in italian, hope you understand)
and
can't convert Char to LPWSTR in the 2 argument

This code compiles fine with code::blocks and dev c++ but in vs it doesn't

Comment: Error message matches the title of [Argument of type "char \*" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611865/argument-of-type-char-is-incompatible-with-parameter-of-type-lpwstr), which suggests you didn't do much esarching before asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `GetModuleFileName` is a macro definition for `GetModuleFileNameW` if UNICODE is defined and which requires `wchar_t*`. If no UNICODE is defined then `GetModuleFileName` resolves to `GetModuleFileNameA`. The simple fix for you is to use explicitly `GetModuleFileNameA` which accepts `char*`

> This code compiles fine with code::blocks and dev c++ but in vs it doesn't

most probably because with code::blocks you compile with no UNICODE defined, while under VS by default UNICODE is defined.

If you are not using UNICODE, and want to stay with multibyte string (same as in code::blocks) you can disable UNICODE in your Visual Studio build by changing in project properties on General tab -> `Character set` to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`.

[edit]

To avoid problems with UNICODE characters in the path it is recomended to use UNICODE. This requires you to use `std::wstring` which is specialization for `wchar_t`, also instead of `char buffer[MAX_PATH];` you should use `wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];`. `cout << "reading path\n";` would have to be `wcout << L"reading path\n";`. You can also use macros like `TCHAR` or `_T("reading path")`, to make it independently work for UNICODE and non-UNICODE builds.

Comment: ok,now it works, thanks

Comment: While this is a solution, it removes the Unicode support, leaving you with the ASCII character set for all APIs, which breaks international applications on systems not set on the same locale.

Comment: @MarioValentino if your application is intended to show Unicode string with the use of Windows GUI frameworks (MFC o WinAPI) then - you might consider staying with UNICODE build.

Comment: @marcinj have you got an example of non-ASCII file path?

Comment: because a path is C:\Hello\from\ITALY\ and i think that this is ASCII

Comment: You would have to use some accented characters, in my language polish - I can use c:\ąśćń\ół.txt. I suppose without unicode your code would break if path contains unicode characters which does not exists in current code page ( the one returned from GetACP() function).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is related [How I can print the wchar_t values to console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493785/how-i-can-print-the-wchar-t-values-to-console). You must also prefix your strings with `L` to make them wide-char like this

```
std::wcout << L"reading path" << std::endl;
```

This will work well if your application is for Windows only, but you should use the `TEXT("reading path")` macro style otherwise, because even though it's not there by default for other platforms, you can add it easily.

Comment: `cout << "reading path\n";` is perfectly fine when building with or without UNICODE, the problem was with GetModuleFileName

Comment: I'm suggesting you use the Unicode variant to avoid problems with non-ASCII file paths, at least.

Comment: right, this might cause problem